# eye-contact-detection with openface, ready to run, errro: No such file or directory: 'dt.joblib'

Tags: python-2.7, openfaces

I'm trying to run eye contact detection algorithm with openface from this github website [here](https://github.com/pashpashpash/Eye-Contact-Detection-With-OpenFace/tree/master/eye_contact_files). When I go into `easy-run-on-mac` branch and try to run `predictorServer.py` the following error occurs:

> No such file or directory: 'dt.joblib'.

I dont know why this happens because I've already got ***dt.joblib file*** in the folder.

Comment: Make sure to show the community what you've tried. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for assistance. Links to offsite code are discouraged because the link can go dead or change.

Comment: Using visualization tools in the question provides more oversight for others and yourself. You also want to post more of the python traceback error inside the yellow box. use also ``` after the > sign. It gives a grey box and formats the traceback. Poste also your code that you run. It might deviate from the one in the link.